# Why past events reappear in dreams after a certain delay?

Tags: memory, sleep, dreams, long-term-memory

I know that Freud in his "Interpretation of dreams" provides a number of examples of events influencing dreams several days to several months after the event has occurred. For example, a person sees a red bicycle in a shop and a week later may have a dream about riding/fixing/seeing the same type of red bicycle. Freud provides on example where an event took place months before the dream.

My question is: **Has there been any research that explained why there can be a long (4-7 days) delay between a real life event and a dream with elements from the event?**

Just to clarify, these are not recurring dreams, but single occurrence dreams about past experiences. Typically the delay between the event and the dream is several days.

Answer (score 1):

Because memory is consolidated during sleep (and dreaming).

http://learnmem.cshlp.org/content/11/6/671.full

http://psychcentral.com/news/2010/04/26/dreams-are-key-to-memory/13157.html

There are also some psychological benefits from easing painful memories.

http://newscenter.berkeley.edu/2011/11/23/dream-sleep/

Comment: I'm aware of memory consolidation, and would expect it to happen on the next night, maybe 2 nights from the event. The phenomenon I'm talking about takes 4+ days and I find it hard to believe that a memory of some trivial details could be lingering around the brain for so long before being consolidated.

Comment: some memory needs more than 4 days to consolidate (even years to integrate with other memories). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep_and_memory